# How to notify user a new version of Alexa skill available?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-notification

I have an Alexa skill. If I upload new version my Skill to store, How can I notify existing users to update the skill? Is it possible to give custom notification message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in mobile apps, skill user **doesn't have to manually update the skill**. Once a user enable your skill, that user will always have the latest version of the skill.

When you start working on the next version of your skill, you will have a live version and development version. Both the live version and the development version of your skill are shown on the developer console.

When you submit your new version for certification, both versions remain in your list until the new version is certified. Once the new version is certified, it becomes live and replaces the previous live version. All the existing users will have the live/latest version of your skill. A new development version is then created so that you can continue making updates.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, **there is no way** to send notifications to your users.